# Define a dashboard panel with child resize logic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, panel

I am trying to write a XAML UI in WPF where the main window container (a panel) would host children.

The tricky part is I want the children to resize when the window resizes (e.g. when it's being maximized on a screen) and I want them to occupy the maximum of the available space without stretching.
But at the same time I would like them to be allowed to wrap like a wrap panel when possible.

I have designed a quick mockup for easier understanding.

[Image mockup on Imgur (25.2KB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUdQT.png)

The top one shows a panel hosting 3 elements which all share the same width and the same height. Two are on the first line, the third one takes advantage of the 2nd line to display.
If all were displayed on the first line, they would be of a smaller width.

The bottom one shows a panel hosting 8 elements which all share the same width and the same height (smaller than in the first mockup so they can fit in one screen). The first two lines have 3 elements each while the last line has only 2.

My initial idea was to use a Stackpanel but they strech your child elements and, as far as I know, they don't allow dynamic sizing of their children depending on the number of elements.

Then I had a look at the wrappanel which does the wrapping very nicely but requires you to set the children size in order to do its magic (I might have missed something but I couldn't find a way around it).

Do you have any idea how I could implement this behaviour while keeping my pannel flexible?

The application which is going to use it will have a different number of children to put in the panel depending on the user's settings.

Ah, I forgot to mention that there should obviously be no vertical scrolling, everything should fit on one screen like a dashboard. That's the point of this panel, make sure that everything fits but displays as big as possible, with no distortion.

If you have any question, just ask.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you take a look at [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx)? It might do what you want by just setting its `Columns` or `Rows` property.

Comment: Doing like Clemens said and embedding your items in a `ViewBox` to adjust/address potential resolution issues and you should be golden.